# No output by insertion sort for a custom test case

Tags: java, sorting

I have this code for insertion sort which is failing to give an output for a test case..

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void insertionSortPart2(int[] ar)
    {       
           // Fill up the code for the required logic here
           // Manipulate the array as required
           // The code for Input/Output is already provided
        int n =ar.length;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
            {int k= ar[i];

             int j=i-1;
             while(ar[j]>k && j>-1)
                 {
                 ar[j+1]=ar[j];
                 j--;
             }
             ar[j+1]=k;
             printArray(ar);

        }
    }  



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int s = in.nextInt();
       int[] ar = new int[s];
       for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
            ar[i]=in.nextInt(); 
       }
       insertionSortPart2(ar);    

    }    
    private static void printArray(int[] ar) {
      for(int n: ar){
         System.out.print(n+" ");
      }
        System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

The test case for which this does not return an output is
9 8 6 7 3 5 4 1 2

error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

I cannot figure out why..
It works correctly for 1 4 3 5 6 2

Comment: `while(ar[j]>k && j>-1)` is a prime suspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with your while loop and this is the line where you might be getting exception `while(ar[j]>k && j>-1)`. You are trying to access array using negative index i.e. -1. You get this exception when you try to access elements outside of either lower or outer bound of an array.

- When i is 1, j is 0 by `j=i-1`
- You enter the while loop since a[1] > a[0] i.e. 9 > 8
- You do j-- where value of j becomes -1
- You come back to while (`while(ar[j]>k && j>-1)`) try to access a[j] ie.. a[-1] and hence you get ArrayOutOfBoudException.

You may need to check j > -1 before accessing array i.e. reverse your condition in while loop from

```
while(ar[j]>k && j>-1)
```

To

```
while(j>-1 && ar[j]>k)
```

Comment: O I missed tht ..Thnx